# CSS Change radio button color in JFXRadioButton

Tags: css, javafx

I have a problem with styling `JFXRadioButton` from this library :
[jfoenix.com](http://jfoenix.com)

I would like to change the color or  circle, but default class didn't work.  Have you to any ideas?

(Colors for tests only.. )

```
.radioButtonFX .radio:selected {
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}

.radioButtonFX .radio-button .radio:selected {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

I would like also change the color of `JFXRippler` and the line for selected tab in `JFXTabPane`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFXRadioButton` assigns the color from code. This takes precedence over values assigned. The only way to modify this from CSS is using the `-fx-selected-color` and `-fx-unselected-color` properties of the `JFXRadioButton` itself:

```css
.jfx-radio-button {
    -fx-selected-color: yellow;
    -fx-unselected-color: blue;
}
```

As for the rippler color

```css
.jfx-rippler {
    -fx-rippler-fill: lime;
}
```

and the line below the selected tab

```css
.jfx-tab-pane .tab-selected-line {
    -fx-stroke: red;
}
```

Note that there is a [`getCssMetaData` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getCssMetaData--) in `Node`, which allows you to retrieve a list of available properties.

```
radio.getCssMetaData().stream().map(CssMetaData::getProperty).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The last properties should be the one of the JFX control...

This does not work for `JTabPane` however, since those are properties of a child of the `Node`. For that info it seems to be necessary to dig through the code of the default skin for `JFXTabPane`, since JFoenix seems to have done a awful job at writing propert documententatiion for it's classes.

Comment: css properties for jfxradiobutton: 
**-jfx-selected-color**  and **-jfx-unselected-color** (in case anyone else was wondering why it's not working) from http://jfoenix.com/documentation.html#RadioButton