# How to change color of selected RadioButton in JavaFX [CSS]?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I just want to change the color of the fill circle on a RadioButton. Surprisingly I couldn't find this in documentation. Is it possible?

I found this similar thread with a solution that is not working for me: [CSS Change radio button color in JFXRadioButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777882/css-change-radio-button-color-in-jfxradiobutton?rq=1)

Here is how I have tried it (also tried other variations to no avail):

```
.radio-button .radio {
    -fx-selected-color: yellow;
    -fx-unselected-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Here's the documentation for `RadioButton`'s CSS: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#radiobutton. It inherits from `ToggleButton` which means it has the `selected` pseudo class.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp yes just the color of the dot in the center of the button (default is black)

Comment: @Slaw I've already tried adding on :selected to the header but it still doesn't work

Comment: The properties `-fx-selected-color` and `-fx-unselected-color` don't exist. The documentation states that `radio` and `dot` are both `Region`s (in the _Substructure_ section), which means you can set the background color with `-fx-background-color`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-jfx-selected-color` and `-jfx-unselected-color` are not defined in JavaFX. They are attributes from JFoenix ([docs](http://jfoenix.com/documentation.html#RadioButton)). Also `-fx-selected-color` and `-fx-unselected-color` are not available in JavaFX.

To change the color of the dot in the RadioButton you can use the `:selected` pseudoclass like this ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#radiobutton)):

```css
.radio-button:selected .radio .dot {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

Additionally to the `-fx-background-color` you should set `-fx-background-insets: 0;`, because otherwise the dot is not exactly in the center anymore.

The result will look like this:

[image: button]